# What are each of the armor classes for?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-x

When buying armor, you have 5 choices: Light, Medium, Heavy, BLADE, and Skell. What are the advantages and disadvantages of each? From what I can tell so far:

- BLADE armor is good for leveling up (it has EXP bonuses)
- Skell armor is good for skell piloting (lots of Skell bonuses)

... but what are the other armor classes used for? Everyone can equip everything, so is there some reason to not outfit everyone in heavy armor?

Comment: I was about to ask this myself. In Xenoblade, it was clearly marked that equipping heavier armor would lower your agility (and thereby your chance to dodge or hit an enemy). If this kind of mechanic is present in X, it's not clearly marked. There seems to be less of a difference in armor values between the armor types, too. The main difference *might* be skills that come on the store-bought versions, with each class favoring certain types of skills, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: @twobugs Agreed. There's a lot of small things like this that could definitely be explained better, but I'm hoping someone else knows better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the primary differences in ground gear armor classes is their gravity resistance (ie, how susceptible you are to topple), the number of upgrade slots available (light armor has more upgrade slots), and the defense conferred. Heavy armor has less gravity resistance than light armor, so you're more likely to be toppled.

Comment: Heavy Armor, at least storebought, has fewer upgrade slots with 1. Light armor has the most at 5.

Comment: @twobugs Thanks for that, I forget about them because I haven't made extensive use of them yet.

Answer (score -3):

lol the reason is possibilities of upgrade!

most armors come with traits (bonus)

for lv 60 stuff, heavy can be upgraded 6 times, medium 8 times, light 10 times and skell 16 times.

Comment: This ended up in the low-quality queue for length and content. I'm not going to vote to delete, since it's an attempt to answer the question and has specific (correct?) numbers I don't see in the other answer, but I'm still downvoting for being poorly written and vague.